# Data usage from within my router accessing contents via WAN IP

Tags: streaming, bandwidth

I'm using a domain, example.com, which has a WAN IP (as an example) 23.24.25.26. I want to create a plex server with IP 192.168.1.23 on the computer and use example.com to access it.

If I access my router from my internal IP 192.168.1.23/movies it goes directly to my computer so I'm not using my ISP bandwidth to stream the movies in my house.

What happens if I access my movies using example.com/movies from my house (behind my router)?  Does the movie get streamed using my ISP bandwidth?  I have a N750 wireless dual band Netgear router.

I have a limit on my bandwidth and don't want to use it up by accessing it with the domain that I own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this probably won't work (in the simple case, ie where you are using DNS to point to the external site) - because most routers can't handle the redirection from external back to internal IP address on the LAN side of the network.

Assuming your router can somehow do this then the data would not go through the ISP - the reason for this is that the Destination IP address is on/known to the router, so it will not be directed out the default gateway.

Comment: My isp only blocks port 80 so I can use another port.  I'm using sitelutions to route the domain to my ip

Comment: Port blocking has nothing to do with the problem - the way routers work will be where the problem is - ie the external IP address will be bound to the WAN/External facing port - which means by the time the request to that IP is made, it has already traversed the external interface of the router, when it needs to be put back on the LAN interface.   Tracking the return connection from the server is likewise an issue for similar purposes.

Comment: The solution - while tricky and unpalatable - is to run split DNS so your LAN gets a different IP  (ie the internal one) compared with everything else.  Setting this up is not trivial.